# Auto fill text boxes based on drop down selected

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am working on .asp webpage. I used javascript as the script language. I have a drop down with values populated from agencies table in database. In that agencies table , there are many other columns like contact information, phone number ,E-mail etc. If user selects an agency from drop down , the text boxes below the drop down contains contact information. I want the text boxes to be auto filled from database when user selects an agency name from the drop down. I tried searching in Google but I could not find proper resources.

Note- Drop down database and Contact information are from same table.

Comment: When you said **I want the text boxes to be auto filled from database when user selects an agency name from the drop down.** On each dropwdown select you want to go to database. Right? to fetch the corresponding information. If so, Why auto fill ? Why not go to database using ajax update panel on dropdown record change event ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to fill data into text boxes.

An example link about how to implement AJAX in asp.net:

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4704/implementing-ajax-in-aspnet/

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the dropdown's AutoPostBack property to true, and handle it's onchange event to do the searching to the database and filling of your controls.